# Unable to install h5pyviewer through conda

Tags: conda, h5py

I was trying to install [h5pyviewer](https://anaconda.org/auto/h5pyviewer) through conda

```
conda activate envName
conda install -c auto h5pyviewer
```

Upon running the above, I received the following error-

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
- h5pyviewer
Current channels: 
- https://conda.anaconda.org/auto/win-64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/auto/noarch  
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64            
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch            
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64               
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch               
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64           
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch           
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64         
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch               
To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're looking for, 
navigate to https://anaconda.org and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Python version 3.6

Conda version  4.10.1

Comment: According to `PyPl` this is a somewhat dated (2015) package. In your case it might have been instaled directly from there (with `pip`?) rather via conda.

Comment: Use HDFView from The HDF Group for an update to date HDF5 file viewer. It's really nice (and built on Java, so no Python dependencies). [Link to download HDFView](https://www.hdfgroup.org/downloads/hdfview/)

Comment: You can also try [Argos](https://github.com/titusjan/argos), See the installation instructions for Anaconda [here](https://github.com/titusjan/argos#installing-argos-with-anaconda)